# Optional type in field and code, is it safe?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I have a class like this:

```
class Environment {

    somelib.SomeType someOptionalDep = null;

    public void doSomething() {
        boolean found = false;
        try {
            Class.forName("somelib.SomeType");
            found = true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
        if (found) {
            someOptionalDep = new somelib.SomeType();
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

`somelib` is an optional package: exists in compile time, but excluded from the base jar. In fact, this code works without the dependency (Oracle Java HotSpot 1.8.0_111 on Debian 8), but is this really safe?

**Note:** I *know*, that I could wrap optional functionalities in separated classes, but this whould be too complicated in some cases.

**EDIT:**

From Oracle's documentation of `NoClassDefFoundError`:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a `ClassLoader` instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the `new` expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

Sadly, it says nothing explicitly about declaration or loaded-but-not-executed code.

Comment: What's the point? Why not just catch the `NoClassDefFoundError`?

Comment: Is a field declaration safe with a potentially non-existent type?

Answer (score 1):

no, this won't work. when your class is loaded, the VM will also look for `SomeType`, and throw an error. The correct way to do this is to create an interface which you include also in base.jar, have SomeType implement the interface, then do:

```
class Environment {
  SomeInterface someOptionalDep = null;
    public void doSomething() {
      try {
        Class c = Class.forName("somelib.SomeType");        
        someOptionalDep = c.newInstance();
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException e) {
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it can work, unless the Environment class wasn't loaded in the first place.

Comment: @Roberto Attias: As @shmosel also says, I have tried this with Oracle Java HotSpot 1.8.0_111 on Debian 8, and worked. " `someOptionalDep` " stores an instance of a third-party library class, which has no portable interface in general (maybe `Object someOptionalDep`).

Comment: I stand corrected. and actually, this should guarantee that any JVM adhering to the specs will behave like that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4

Comment: thinking some more about this, while it works, it can make your code very fragile. can you provide an estimate about how many functions in the library you use, and what do you do when those are not available?

Comment: What is reference to the JLS for? The link leads to the "Initialization of Classes and Interfaces" and it is not related to the question.

Comment: the initialization of the class is the first time the class is processed. The document specifies a class is "initialized immediately before"/ A JVM adhering to the spec cannot initialize, say, when an import for the class is found in another class.

Comment: @RobertoAttias "...and what do you do when those are not available?" - There are multiple `Environment` types. If a critical resource is not available (and in other cases), then a checker method (`isAvailable()`) will be returned with false, this is to indicate that this `AnyEnvironment` is not available currently. With the above anti-pattern solution I could significantly reduce amount of code that would be more readable.

Comment: @RobertoAttias "the initialization of the class is the first time the class is processed" - no. Loading of a class is the first time it is processed. As [JLS 12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2) says the class loading is defined not by JLS, but by [JVMS 5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3). To obtain a list of actions that provoke class loading one probably need to find all wordings like "X is resolved" and "X is loaded" in JVMS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your primary question is stated in the comment

> Is a field declaration safe with a potentially non-existent type?

and by safe you seem to mean "does not cause `NoClassDefFoundError`".

Before answering the question itself I'd like to say that you're better off not doing it that way. Having a non-existing type in your code makes it unnecessarily complicated - which is anything but safe. Optional dependencies are better to be handled by a kind of gateway that separates your business logic from the dependency. Additional interface, as suggested by Roberto Attias, is an example. You could also introduce your own interface with to implementations: one delegates all calls to the optional dependency, and the other doing nothing.

---

Technically, the answer is **yes**.

JVM tends to do things as lazily as possible - especially class loading. When a class is loaded JVM will only load its superclass and superinterfaces, but not other types used in the code.

Moreover, even reading and writing a field that has a non-existing type does *not* itself provoke class loading (and `NoClassDefFoundError`). This is possible because

- if you're reading a field then class loading can be postponed until you actually use it
- if you're writing a non-null value then you've already loaded the type to create the instance
- if you're writing a null to a field then the type doesn't matter (since null can be assigned to any value)

BTW, the same holds for parameters and return values of methods.

Comment: "Optional dependencies are better to be handled by a kind of gateway that separates your business logic from the dependency." - Good point in general, but IMO this particular case is among the exceptions. My package is a lightweight abstraction over some platform dependent resources, no busyness logic could be implemented in it.

Comment: @DávidHorváth From this and your other comment it seems like the `Environment` may already be used similarly to what i tried to described, i.e. it safely encapsulates access to `SomeType`, provides it to business logic and does nothing more. If so, that's OK. Otherwise, that's OK as well :) since it's your deliberate choice and you're the only one in position to decide.